# OpenDocument file giving text for Yahoo email

Tags: email, yahoo

Suppose I've got an OpenDocument file giving text of a Yahoo email I want to send, italics, boldface and all. If I copy it and paste into Compose buffer, will it retain the italics and boldfacing? If not, how can I achieve that effect? Only with my fingers, or making it an attachment? Do Emacs and/or LibreOffice offer a way to prepare for that?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this using LibreOffice Writer by creating some text in different formats (normal. italics, bold, underlined) then highlighting the text, copying and then pasting into a Yahoo email account using Thunderbird and it worked fine.

[image]